# Robot not able to import .java library

Tags: jython, robotframework

I am trying to import the 'SwingLibrary' into my Robot project and have had a lot of issues with it. I was able to work around my first error that seems very common by removing the version number from the file name:

```
Importing test library 'SwingLibrary' failed: ImportError: No module named SwingLibrary
```

Now everything is named SwingLibrary (jar & xml included) so I got a little further but I am now seeing the error:

```
Importing test library 'SwingLibrary' failed: Expected class or module, got javapackage.
```

I know Robot is supposed to know when it's trying to import a python or jython package but for some reason it doesn't seem to be working here. I did not have an issue importing the java version of Selenium or any of the standard libraries.

Comment: Did add to CLASSPATH?

>The SwingLibrary.jar needs to be in the class path during execution

Comment: Yep, and tried moving the library around, even had the jar file in multiple locations hoping somewhere would work